# tar gz file contains corrupt jar files after Maven build

Tags: maven, jar, tar, maven-assembly-plugin, corrupt

I have a pom.xml and separate assembly-descriptor.xml file.  The end result is a tar.gz file which contains my tomcat webapp and some jar files.  When I build this on my local dev box (Mac OS 10.7 and Maven 3.0.3) the resulting tar.gz contains a valid jar file.  When the build runs on our build box (Jenkins on linux server/Maven 3.0.3) and gets deployed to the production server, the jar file is nearly twice the size it should be and is corrupt.  I can reproduce the doubling/corruption problem locally when I change the version of the maven assembly plugin to 2.3 or 2.4.  When I set it to 2.1 or 2.2 or no version (it defaults to 2.2 beta 5) it works locally.  But no matter what version I choose, the build fails during the tar gz step on the build box. (Local java version = 1.6.0_37 and build system is 1.6.0_34 but I don't think this discrepancy is to blame.)
Here is my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <finalName>${project.build.finalName}_${project.version}</finalName>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
            <attach>true</attach>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>package-tar-gz</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>...
```

`
Here is the assembly descriptor (assembly-descriptor.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/tomcat</directory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
      <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.war</exclude>
      </excludes>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Finally, another difference between the local build and the production build is that the production build uses a local repository and my local build does not.  I've not given this much attention because I'm able to reproduce the jar file doubling/corruption problem locally (i.e. sans local repo issue).

Comment: Can you clarify what **But no matter what version I choose, the build fails during the tar gz ** means? Can you show the log output?

Comment: Sorry, that was misleading.  The build is "successful" in all cases, all versions.  What I meant was, the jar files are corrupted during the official build no matter what version of the assembly plugin I choose.  What is odd is that I can repro the problem on my local build using assembly plugin versions 2.3 and 2.4.  I read another post on this site that indicated you could specify not to compress jar files during the assembly packaging but the 'compress' element was not understood.

Comment: Solution: this was fixed for me by making sure the maven assembly plugin version (2.4) was aligned/compatible with the assembly schema version (1.1.2).  Also, and more importantly, the fileset definition was funky.  Once I rewrote it and simplified it, things worked fine.  In particular, there was a strange definition to filter out war files for one directory then a second definition to include war files.  I think this combo was not well-formatted and worked on one platform and not another.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing true, this might be the culprit

Comment: This worked, although for me it is not intuitive. Maybe we should verify what this flag actually does. Thanks.